# backbone view in router lost after creation

Tags: variables, object, backbone.js, view, router

When I try to associate my router's public variable this.currentView to a newly created view, the view gets lost, the public variable is null instead of containing the newly created view.

```
var self=this;

        var watchListsCollection = new WatchlistCollection;
        watchListsCollection.url = "watchlists";
        user.fetch().done(function() {
            watchListsCollection.fetch().done(function () {
                loggedUser.fetch().done(function () {

                    self.currentView = new UserView(user, watchListsCollection,loggedUser);

                });
            });
        });

        alert(this.currentView); //null
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fetch()` calls you do are firing asynchronous AJAX requests, meaning the code in your `done` handlers are not going to be executed untill the server calls return. Once you've executed `user.fetch()` the browser will fire off a request and then continue running your program and alert `this.currentView` without waiting for the requests to finish.

The sequence of events is basically going to be

1. call `user.fetch()`
2. alert `this.currentView`
3. call `watchListsCollection.fetch()`
4. call `loggedUser.fetch()`
5. set the value of `self.currentView`

You will not be able to see the value of your currentView before the last server request have completed.

If you change your code to

```
var self=this;

var watchListsCollection = new WatchlistCollection;
watchListsCollection.url = "watchlists";
user.fetch().done(function() {
    watchListsCollection.fetch().done(function () {
        loggedUser.fetch().done(function () {

            self.currentView = new UserView(user, watchListsCollection,loggedUser);
            alertCurrentView();
        });
    });
});

function alertCurrentView() {
    alert(this.currentView);
}
```

You should see the correct value displayed. Now, depending on what you intend to use your `this.currentView` for that might or might not let you fix whatever issue you have, but there's no way you're not going to have to wait for all the requests to complete before it's available. If you need to do something with it straight away you should create your `UserView` immediately and move the `fetch()` calls into that view's `initialize()`.

Answer (score 0):

fetch() is asynchronous, but you check your variable right after you've started your task. Probably these tasks, as they supposed to be just reads, should be run in parallel. And forget making a copy of `this`, try `_.bind` instead according to the Airbnb styleguide: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript

```
var tasks = [];
tasks.push(user.fetch());
tasks.push(watchListsCollection.fetch());
tasks.push(loggedUser.fetch());

Promise.all(tasks).then(_.bind(function() {
  this.currentView = new UserView(user, watchListsCollection, loggedUser);
}, this));
```

or using ES6 generators:

```
function* () {
  var tasks = [];

  tasks.push(user.fetch());
  tasks.push(watchListsCollection.fetch());
  tasks.push(loggedUser.fetch());

  yield Promise.all(tasks);

  this.currentView = new UserView(user, watchListsCollection, loggedUser);
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use Promise or generators you might as well use `Function.prototype.bind` instead of `_.bind`.  It works starting from IE9 :)